# Writing directly to memory location in C works in microcontrollers but not on PC

Tags: c, microcontroller

I'd like to know why something like the C code below works in microcontrollers but not in mainstream computers:

```
// 1. Get memory location of GPIOA SET Register.
uint32_t *gpioa = (uint32_t *)(0x40020000 + 0x18);

// 2. Set bit to 1 to enable it.
*gpioa |= (1<<5);
```

Statement `1.` works on computers, but trying to access the memory location in any way leads to a segmentation fault.

Is the operating system blocking direct memory access in this way?

Comment: protection, imagine if it were this easy to poke around the memory in the computer, passwords being used by other programs, dig into the kernel, crash it or change it on the fly.   there are windows tricks too but on linux look up mmap(), will let you punch through and get a pointer that you can use the same way you are used to on a microcontroller (likely have to run as root to execute)

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for sharing `mmap()`, I'll check it out. I would have thought that there would be at least a few read-only, fixed memory locations on an x86 which can be accessed directly by any program. Maybe something like CPU temperature, speed etc. I can't find anything that let's me read the registers directly, I'd have to go through the kernel.

Comment: there is an i/o protection map (well used to be, I think it is renamed/new, have not punched through in years now using a kernel driver) which you could have a simple kernel driver change so that applications could punch through without being trapped.  popular back when there were parallel ports and you could use them to bit bang things like jtag or other.  I have seen/read about the current chips, dont remember the name of this protection logic/blob they use now, easier to just mmap.

Comment: how mmap does this is up to the kernel/drivers.  If you think about it there are different things it can do, it may let you punch through without being trapped, it may still cause a protection fault but then perform the transaction for you and return the result (just like a virtual machine), or it may fault.  Note that for some reason you have better odds getting mmap() to succeed if you use larger memory chunks, trying 0x1000 bytes of space even though you only need one or a few registers may fail, of so try 0x10000000 bytes.

Comment: @old_timer- Thanks for the tips, I'll keep that in mind when playing with it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, on typical multi-user systems, the operating system controls access to memory.

Your process has only a **virtual** address space. The operating sets special registers or other features in the hardware to regulate your address space. Parts of your virtual address space are mapped to physical memory, and parts are not mapped at all. (A mapping specifies how a virtual address is translated to a physical address.) The operating system also determines whether you can read memory, write memory, or execute instructions from memory.

At times, the operating system may change what parts of memory your process can access. It may keep data your process is not currently using on disk and mark that part of your virtual address space inaccessible. When your process tries to access it, the hardware generates an exception, and the kernel handles the exception by reading the data from disk to memory, marking the memory accessible to your process, and restarting your process at the instruction that generated the exception.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Eric Postpischil's answer, the memory locations of various microcontroller registers are different for every model of microntroller you may try to program. So not only is your code not portable to a PC (where it segfaults), but it may also segfault or misbehave on a different microcontroller (unless it's the same family of microntroller, and they're specifically designed to be compatible).